# Creating a gzip stream from separately compressed chunks

Tags: compression, gzip, zlib

I like to be able to generate a gzip (.gz) file using concurrent CPU threads. I.e., I would be deflating separate chunks from the input file with separately initialized `z_stream` records.

The resulting file should be readable by zlib's inflate() function in a classic single threaded operation.

Is that possible? Even if it requires customized zlib code? The only requirement would be that the currently existing zlib's inflate code could handle it.

**Update**

The [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/) source code demonstrates how it works. It uses some sophisticated optimizations to share the dictionary between chunks, keeping the compression rate optimal. It further handles bit packing if a more recent zlib version is used.

Howevever, I like to understand how to roll my own, keeping things simple, without the optimizations `pigz` uses.

And while many consider source code to be the ultimate documentation ([Ed Post, anyone?](http://web.mit.edu/humor/Computers/real.programmers)) I rather have it explained in plain words to avoid misunderstandings. (While the docs actually describe what happens pretty well, they do not explain too well what needs to be done to roll one's own.)

From browsing the code, I figured out this much so far:

It appears that one simply creates each compressed chunk using `deflate(..., Z_SYNC_FLUSH)` instead of using `Z_FINISH`. However, `deflateEnd()` gives an error then, not sure if that can be ignored. And one needs to calculate the final checksum over all chunks manually, though I wonder how to add the checksum at the end. There is also a rather complex `put_trailer()` function for writing a gzip header - I wonder if that could also be handled by zlib's own code for simple cases?

Any clarification on this is appreciated.

Also, **I realize that I should have included asking about writing a zlib stream** the same way, in order to write multithreaded-compressed files to a zip archive. There, I suspect, more simplifications are possible due to the lack of the more complex gzip header.

Comment: I created a tool to create raw deflate stream https://github.com/stokito/deflate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in your question. Each thread has its own `deflate` instance to produce raw deflate data (see `deflateInit2()`), which compresses the chunk of the data fed to it, ending with `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` instead of `Z_FINISH`. Except for the last chunk of data, which you end with a `Z_FINISH`. Either way, this ends each resulting stream of compressed data on a byte boundary. Make sure that you get all of the generated data out of `deflate()`. Then you can concatenate all the compressed data streams. (In the correct order!) Precede that with a gzip header that you generate yourself. It is trivial to do that (see [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952)). It can just be a constant 10-byte sequence if you don't need any additional information included in the header (e.g. file name, modification date). The gzip header is not complex.

You can also compute the CRC-32 of each uncompressed chunk in the same thread or a different thread, and combine those CRC-32's using `crc32_combine()`. You need that for the gzip trailer.

After all of the compressed streams are written, ending with the compressed stream that was ended with a `Z_FINISH`, you append the gzip trailer. All that is is the four-byte CRC-32 and the low four bytes of the total uncompressed length, both in little-endian order. Eight bytes total.

In each thread you can either use `deflateEnd()` when done with each chunk, or if you are reusing threads for more chunks, use `deflateReset()`. I found in pigz that it is much more efficient to leave threads open and `deflate` instances open in them when processing multiple chunks. Just make sure to use `deflateEnd()` for the last chunk that thread processes, before closing the thread. Yes, the error from `deflateEnd()` can be ignored. Just make sure that you've run `deflate()` until `avail_out` is not zero to get all of the compressed data.

Doing this, each thread compresses its chunk with no reference to any other uncompressed data, where such references would normally improve the compression when doing it serially. If you want to get more advanced, you can feed each thread the chunk of uncompressed data to compress, *and* the last 32K of the previous chunk to provide history for the compressor. You do this with `deflateSetDictionary()`.

Still more advanced, you can reduce the number of bytes inserted between compressed streams by sometimes using `Z_PARTIAL_FLUSH`'s until getting to a byte boundary. See pigz for the details of that.

Even more advanced, but slower, you can append compressed streams at the bit level instead of the byte level. That would require shifting every byte of the compressed stream twice to build a new shifted stream. At least for seven out of every eight preceding compressed streams. This eliminates all of the extra bits inserted between compressed streams.

A zlib stream can be generated in exactly the same way, using `adler32_combine()` for the checksum.

Your question about zlib implies a confusion. The zip format does not use the zlib header and trailer. [zip has its own structure](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), within which is imbedded raw deflate streams. You can use the above approach for those raw deflate streams as well.

Comment: I am trying to use deflate, adding my own gz header and trailer. With setting bit 4 in wbits, the gz file starts with the 10-byte header `1F 8B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03`, then deflated data `95 58 7B 6F D3 48 ...`, ending with CRC and source length. So far so good. With bit 4 cleared, it starts with `78 DA`, then the same data `95 58 7B 6F D3 48 ...`, and ending with a checksum (Adler?). What do the first 2 bytes do there? If I just prepend the header and add the CRC and origlen, it won't decompress as a .gz file. How do I generate the pure gz stream without header and trailer?

Comment: I think you mean, "How do I generate a raw deflate stream?" If there is no header and trailer, then by definition it is not a gzip or "gz" stream. The documentation in zlib.h says how to make a raw deflate stream. You give `deflateInit2()` a negative `wbits` value.

Comment: The first two bytes of the zlib stream identify it as a zlib stream, and provides the compression method and window size. At the end, the Adler-32 value is stored in big-endian order. (Unlike the gzip wrapper, where the trailer values are stored in little-endian order.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. Got it. BTW, I maintain a zip library written in Xojo (formerly Realbasic), but it's been over 10 years I worked on it and forgot half of it. Thanks for all your quick help. Saved me from browsing more code, and getting my own things done :)  Also, was not aware of Adler being in BE, thanks for pointed that out. I shall revise my zip code now as I've learned a few more things today.

Answer (score 1):

Sure..

http://zlib.net/pigz/

> A parallel implementation of gzip for modern
>   multi-processor, multi-core machines

Comment: Neat. Now, since I've already written my own pthreads-based code to use the standard zlib functions, I wonder if you can tell me what options I need to use to make this work with deflateInit2, or whether this feature actually requires a rewritten zlib, i.e. that I need to use pigz for this? Do you know? (Hold on, reading the docs in the source right now...)

Comment: No i dont know what deflateInit2 entails and havent used this in programming. But i know that pigz compressed files can be decompressed using gunzip, so they must formatted correctly for gzip to handle them i guess.